# How to get the Update Version value from IE11 using C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-11

Is it possible to get the Update Version number from IE11 using C# MVC?

I've tried Request.Browser but that only provides the Major and Minor versions.

I need to find out what the Update version number is so that we can track users that are using the RTM version of IE11.

Unfortunately, some users just never got the update for IE11. We need users to be on the latest version of IE11.

[image: Update Version Number from IE11]

Comment: Request.Browser returns some the browser's capabilities based on browser definition files. The browser's full version is sent in the User-Agent header, available throuh [Request.UserAgent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is the value I get from IE11: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko. I'm looking for the Update Versions. In the picture above I'm looking for 11.0.31

Comment: In any case, you should write your application to support the browsers features, *not* try to detect the browser or demand users use a specific browser version. For example, more and more users will be using Edge from now on.

Comment: I understand and agree, this system was not developed by our company. We outsourced the development and now we're in this mess. Is there any other way to do this other than going through the entire system and changing it?

Comment: Check the request headers using Fiddler. Perhaps some other custom header contains the information. Although, with evergreen browsers, the update version may not have much meaning and will change when the browser decides to update

Comment: Ok, I tried to look at Fiddler. There's no customer header that contains that info. I guess I have to manage this differently :(. Thanks for the help @PanagiotisKanavos